# How to filter the output of the docker logs command?

Tags: bash, docker, logging

I am attempting to filter the output of the docker logs command:

```
docker logs consumer-web-1 | grep NewCoveredBusinessAdded
```

Despite using a pipe and grep, the entire output includes numerous strings, with only one string containing NewCoveredBusinessAdded.

Comment: Is the main container command also writing to stderr?  If you run the program without Docker, do you get the same behavior?  The generic Unix Bourne shell recipe for capturing stderr to would be `... 2>&1 | grep ...`, where the `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout so that `grep` can capture it on its stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Grep by default returns all the line with the provided regex occurrence, probably the `numerous strings` are part of the same line.

You can try to use `awk` for instance:

```bash
docker logs consumer-web-1 | awk '/NewCoveredBusinessAdded/ {getline; print substr($0, {start_substring_index}, {char_length})}'
```

Where `start_substring_index` is the start of the substring you want to start from, and `char_length` is the length of the charachter after the index of the start_substring_index

```bash
docker logs consumer-web-1 | awk '/NewCoveredBusinessAdded/ {getline; print substr($0, 1, 20)}'
```

Comment: Thank good idea, but the 1st output is: docker logs consumer-web-1 | awk '/NewCoveredBusinessAdded/ {getline; print substr($0, {start_substring_index}, {char_length})}'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
 /NewCoveredBusinessAdded/ {getline; print substr($0, >>>  { <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: The 2nd output is the same as original, still plenty of lines

Comment: @Alex can you post your output here? i think that the problem might be that it's a full string without spaces.